# In pytest-allure, how do I capture screenshots when use case execution fails?

Tags: report, pytest, allure

I don't know how to add a plugins to the pytest-allure. I hope you can give me an example. I hope to hook the failure result of the case when the case fails and capture it in the allure report.
My code is as follows： conftest.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pytest
from allure.constants import AttachmentType
from selenium import webdriver

drvier = webdriver.Chrome()

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
outcome = yield
rep = outcome.get_result()
setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
if rep.when == 'call':
    if rep.failed:
        png = item.name + '.png'
        pytest.allure.attach(png, drvier.get_screenshot_as_png(), type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

The following is Main()

```
# coding=utf-8
import subprocess

import pytest

from conf import config_path

def action(case):
pytest.main(['-s', '-q', config_path.testcase_path + case+'.py', '--alluredir', config_path.report_path])

command_report = config_path.allurecmd_path +'allure generate ' + config_path.report_path + ' -o ' + config_path.report_path
print(command_report)
progress = subprocess.Popen(command_report, shell=True)
progress.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   action('Login_test')
```

I hope you can help me solve this problem. thanks！

Comment: I have also tried attaching screenshot without any success. :(